# Python: Using defs in a program about ordering stuff

Tags: python, function, python-3.4

This program is about ordering stuff from a "mail order" house thing.

They sell five products. P1 = 2.98, P2 = 4.5, P3 = 9.98, P4 = 4.49, P5 = 6.87

So this is my code so far.

```
#Imports: None

#Defs:

def userInput1():
    x = int(input("Product Number?"))
    return x
def userInput2():
    q = int(input("Quantity?"))
    return q
def calculations(x,q):
    p1 = 2.98
    p2 = 4.5
    p3 = 9.98
    p4 = 4.49
    p5 = 6.87
    subtotal = q * x
    return subtotal
def final(subtotal):
    print ("Total:", subtotal)
def loop():
    cont = input("Do you want to continue? (yes/no)")
    if cont == 'yes':
        main()
        return
    else:
        final()

def main():
    x = userInput1()
    subtotal = calculations(x,q)
    final(subtotal)
#Driver:
main()
```

I have to use a sentinel controlled loop.

Here's my traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user1\My Documents\Downloads\az_mailorder3.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user1\My Documents\Downloads\az_mailorder3.py", line 46, in main
    subtotal = calculations(x,q)
NameError: name 'q' is not defined
```

Here's how it should work.

```
Product number?: 1
Quantity?: 2
Continue?(yes/no): yes
Product number?: 2
Quantity?: 5
Continue?(yes/no): yes
Product number?: 3
Quantity?: 3
Continue?(yes/no): yes
Product number?: 4
Quantity?: 1
Continue?(yes/no): no
Total: $62.89
```

There's probably deeper problems.

Comment: How do you know your `SyntaxError` is with a return statement?

Comment: It said syntax error when i run the module, then the cursor is after the return. @JoelCornett

Comment: Which return? I count 4 return statements in your code. You need to provide more information if you want your question answered. How about posting verbatim the full text of the traceback you get when you run the module?

Comment: No traceback. Dialog box pops up, near the first one `return x` with the cursor immediately after return. @JoelCornett

Comment: Ah. I see. You're missing a closing parentheses (`)`) in `userInput1()`. Is that it?

Comment: Removing the returns give me an invalid syntax dialog box with the cursor pointing imeediately after the second word def

Comment: That is it, and we have a deeper problem. Hold on, editing question now.

Comment: Dialog box? How are you running the python script? Also, `raw_input` should give you a `NameError` in python 3.

Comment: @APerson it works. We have deeper problems. userinput1() not defined as u see above

Comment: You don't call `userinput1()` in `main()`; you call `userinput()`. Is this what your code says?

Comment: @JoelCornett Ok i see tracebacks now, so thats fine. and I fixed `raw_input` to `input`

Comment: @APerson Fixed that in the question and in my program, same error.

Comment: You didn't capitalize the "I" in "userInput" when you call it in `main()`. _Does this fix it?_

Comment: @APerson Really sorry to put you through this, but I feel bad for giving so many stupid typing mistakes.

Comment: @APerson Fixed capping the I, and now I am able to enter the product number, then the traceback comes up, saying q's not defined. As you see above in my edited traceback

Comment: Your code in `main()` as it appears does not call `userInput2()` nor does it assign the result of that call to `q`: `q = userInput2()` hence the `NameError: name 'q' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are a newbie to programming (I can feel that from your code) and also this problem seems a school homework which is quite easy and also you don't want to try hard debugging it (You need to debug a lot to be a good programmer)
Here I am presenting your code to you with proper comments why your code is going wrong.
Start reading from the main function (not from the first line)

```
def userInput1():
    x = int(input("Product Number?"))
    return x
def userInput2():
    q = int(input("Quantity?"))
    return q
def calculations(x,q):
    p1 = 2.98
    p2 = 4.5
    p3 = 9.98
    p4 = 4.49
    p5 = 6.87
    subtotal = q * x
#here you are multiplying the item number by quantity 
#not the price by quantity (use proper if else to check price for item number
# return to main function again for more comments
    return subtotal
def final(subtotal):
    print ("Total:", subtotal)
#nothing wrong here but since we have declared subtotal as global (remember that?)
#so no need to pass subtotal by argument.
def loop():
    cont = input("Do you want to continue? (yes/no)")
    if cont == 'yes':
        main()
        return
    else:
        final()
#you are calling final() but you declared with argument (are you mad?)
#now check final function

def main():
    x = userInput1()
#Where you are taking input from user for quantity??
#first take quantity as input q = userInput2() 
    subtotal = calculations(x,q)
#now every time you call main function your subtotal will be revised
#remember teacher talking about global and local variables?
#subtotal needs to be global (declare it somewhere outside the functions
#now even if subtotal is global you need to increment it (not reassign)
# use subtotal += calculations(x,q)
#now check your calculations function 
    final(subtotal)
#you are calling final subtotal but where the hell you calling your loop?
#call it before calling final and now check your loop function
main()
```

hopefully by now you are able to write correct code
but even if you are not able to write correct code by now [here](http://ideone.com/RHrEZz) is something for your help. But try to write code by yourself first. Happy Debugging :)

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot for my coding. There were a lot of stupid errors :)